# Rename volume with bizarre name

Tags: macos

A MacBook Air with a SSD, the boot drive, name consisting of 220 double-quote characters.

MBA 2014 with Sierra 10.12.6 (not high sierra)

These did not work:

- From a finder window, R-click in name column Dialog popup - "The name  can't be used.  Try using a name with fewer characters, or with no punctuation marks"
- From finder window, sidebar - just to be exhaustive, same result
- From the Info dialog.
- From the terminal.

  - At the user home directory:  `diskutil rename /Volumes/oldname  new name` .  I get the message "could not find disk for /Volumes".  I tried using single-quotes around *oldname*, but same result

Answer (score 1):

`diskutil rename` lets you specify the original location in ways other than by name.

I think some variation on this will work for you: `diskutil rename disk1s1 "NewHDDName2"`

Running `diskutil list` first should let you figure out the identifier for the volume.